# How to center a block of rows in the middle of a page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out how to center these rows in the middle of the page. I got the template from Bootstrap and was modifying it to fit my webpage. [image] I'd like for the rows to be centered just like the text above it. This used to be a checkout form example but I've removed the items to the right of the rows.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid first name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid last name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="birthmonth">Birthday</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="birthmonth" required>
              <option value="">Month</option>
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
              <option>March</option>
              <option>April</option>
              <option>May</option>
              <option>June</option>
              <option>July</option>
              <option>August</option>
              <option>September</option>
              <option>October</option>
              <option>November</option>
              <option>December</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid month.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Day</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthday" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Day is required.
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="birthyear">Year</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthyear" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Year is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="country">University</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>UC Berkeley</option>
              <option>UC Davis</option>
              <option>UC Irvine</option>
              <option>UCLA</option>
              <option>UC Riverside</option>
              <option>UC San Francisco</option>
              <option>UC Santa Barbara</option>
              <option>UC Santa Cruz</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid university.
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>United States</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>California</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Zip code required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="email">Password</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="address">Repeat Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter the same password.
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your CSS so we can help you with your solution

Comment: he is using bootstrap

Comment: @E tom so do you want the whole form at center?

Comment: Try using the class `justify-content-center` for the first opening div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Klooven said, adding `justify-content-center` will fix it.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="firstName">First name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Valid first name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Valid last name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
          <label for="birthmonth">Birthday</label>
          <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="birthmonth" required>
              <option value="">Month</option>
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
              <option>March</option>
              <option>April</option>
              <option>May</option>
              <option>June</option>
              <option>July</option>
              <option>August</option>
              <option>September</option>
              <option>October</option>
              <option>November</option>
              <option>December</option>
            </select>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please select a valid month.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <label for="zip">Day</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthday" placeholder="" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Day is required.
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="birthyear">Year</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthyear" placeholder="" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Year is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="country">University</label>
        <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>UC Berkeley</option>
              <option>UC Davis</option>
              <option>UC Irvine</option>
              <option>UCLA</option>
              <option>UC Riverside</option>
              <option>UC San Francisco</option>
              <option>UC Santa Barbara</option>
              <option>UC Santa Cruz</option>
            </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please select a valid university.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
          <label for="country">Country</label>
          <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>United States</option>
            </select>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please select a valid country.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <label for="state">State</label>
          <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>California</option>
            </select>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid state.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="zip">Zip</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Zip code required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email">Password</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="address">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please enter the same password.
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use margin: 0 auto; in this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row ">
 <div class="col-md-8 col-offset-md-2 order-md-1" style="margin:0 auto">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid first name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Valid last name is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="birthmonth">Birthday</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="birthmonth" required>
              <option value="">Month</option>
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
              <option>March</option>
              <option>April</option>
              <option>May</option>
              <option>June</option>
              <option>July</option>
              <option>August</option>
              <option>September</option>
              <option>October</option>
              <option>November</option>
              <option>December</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid month.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Day</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthday" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Day is required.
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="birthyear">Year</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthyear" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Year is required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="country">University</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>UC Berkeley</option>
              <option>UC Davis</option>
              <option>UC Irvine</option>
              <option>UCLA</option>
              <option>UC Riverside</option>
              <option>UC San Francisco</option>
              <option>UC Santa Barbara</option>
              <option>UC Santa Cruz</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid university.
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>United States</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please select a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
              <option value="">Choose...</option>
              <option>California</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Zip code required.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="email">Password</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="address">Repeat Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please enter the same password.
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may notice that this is not working properly .. you are not following bootstrap rules and you cannot use col-md-8 like this without any row/container .. your layout is broken in this case. Also when using bootstrap better rely on provided classes than adding our own style. It's not wrong but it can give you some strange behavior is some cases

Comment: hmm.. you are right we cannot use col-md-8 like this without any row/container. But in this case it is working right when i am doing full page snippet. Thanks @TemaniAfif for giving right information.

Comment: it's seems right but it's not that's why i commented ;) .. add row/container and you will see the difference and thus understand why it's not correct

Comment: hmm.. i added now its working fine in every case.. thanks @TemaniAfif